# Group and sort blog posts by date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've searched all over web and have not found the answer. I'm trying to have a very standard archive option for my blog based on date. A request to url blog.com/archive/2009 shows all posts in 2009, blog.com/archive/2009/11 shows all posts in November 2009 etc. I found two different of code but not very helpful to me.

```
def display_by_date
 year = params[:year]
 month = params[:month]
 day = params[:day]
 day = '0'+day if day && day.size == 1
 @day = day
 if (year && month && day)
   render(:template => "blog/#{year}/#{month}/#{date}")
 elsif year
  render(:template => "blog/#{year}/list")
 end
end

def archive
 year = params[:year]
 month = params[:month]
 day = params[:day]
 day = '0'+day if day && day.size == 1
 if (year && month && day)
   @posts_by_month = Blog.find(:all, :conditions => ["year is?", year])
 else
   @posts_by_month = Blog.find(:all).group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B") }
 end
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? How to do such things in general? How this two snippets work?

Comment: No those two snippets are just me trying to get it to work. My question is how can I sort blog posts just by date. For example like this site http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2010/04/18/. If you remove 18, then you see all posts made in that month and when you remove 04, you see all posts made in 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I've managed to get it to work. If you go to 'blog/2010' you see all posts made in 2010, and if you go to 'blog/2010/apr' you see all posts made in 2010 april etc.

```
def archive
 year = params[:year]
 month = params[:month]
 day = params[:day]
 if (year && month && day)
  requested_date = Date.new(year.to_i, Date.parse(month).month.to_i, day.to_i)
  from = requested_date - 1
  to = requested_date + 1
  @posts_by_month = Blog.find(:all, :conditions => ["due BETWEEN ? AND ?", from, to])
 elsif (year && month)
  requested_month = Date.new(year.to_i, Date.parse(month).month.to_i)
  end_month = requested_month.end_of_month
  @posts_by_month = Blog.find(:all, :conditions => ["due BETWEEN ? AND ?", requested_month, end_month])
 else
  requested_year = Date.new(year.to_i)
  @posts_by_month = Blog.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", requested_year, requested_year.end_of_year ])
 end
end

#routes.rb
map.connect 'blog/:year/:month/:day',
:controller => 'blogs',
:action => 'archive',
:year => /\d{4}/,
:month => /\w{3}/,
:day => /\d{2}/,
:day => nil,
:month => nil
```

I don't know if this is 'good' code, but I'm sure someone can make it even better. I'd appreciate it if someone did.

Comment: This appears to be another question, not an answer… :)

Comment: Lol you're right. I'm trying to figure it out and I'll update the post when done.

Answer (score 0):

I updated sent-hil's answer for Rails 4. As with him, I don't know if this is "good" code but it seems to be working for me. I will update this post if I find/make any improvements.

```
  def archive
    year = params[:year]
    month = params[:month]
    day = params[:day]

    if (year && month && day)
      requested_date = Date.new(year.to_i, Date.parse(month).month.to_i, day.to_i)
      from = requested_date - 1
      to = requested_date + 1
      @posts = Post.find_by_sql([ "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", from, to])
    elsif (year && month)
      requested_month = Date.new(year.to_i, Date.parse(month).month.to_i)
      end_month = requested_month.end_of_month
      @posts = Post.find_by_sql([ "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", requested_month, end_month ])
    else
      requested_year = Date.new(year.to_i)
      @posts = Post.find_by_sql([ "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", requested_year, requested_year.end_of_year ])
    end
  end

#routes.rb
  match ':controller/:action/:year/(:month)/(:day)', via: [:get],
    :controller => "posts",
    :action => "archive",
    :year => /\d{4}/,
    :month => /\w+/,
    :day => /\d{2}/
```

Instead of blog I have used "posts" and paths are of the form www.site.com/posts/archive/2015/September/20